# 3D RFID LF coil antenna - resonance

Tags: antenna, coil, rfid, resonance

I'm designing a 3D 125 kHz RFID only-receiver (you can think about it as a field detector - the tag will not respond with classic field load modulation), which will have three separate coils in XYZ coordinates to receive field in every orientation.

I want to sum the signal from three coils in a single resonant circuit (I can't simply make three separate circuits and sum the signals with an op-amp). I've found some Microchip application notes tackling this topic but I couldn't find anything conclusive.

I have two ideas about the circuit:

[image]

I would like to hear your ideas. Which circuit would be most suitable? Maybe there are better ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Neither is acceptable for your desired goal.  You need antenna *diversity* to achieve this.

Any series/parallel or ratio connection of the three axes, merely results in some 3D vector as the preferred axis, with a null perpendicular to it.  Whereas a single coil gives response in its plane, the sum of three planes, equally weighted, gives the linear sum of them, a new [1,1,1] diagonal plane instead.

For omnidirectional operation, you must detect each axis independently.  You need three receivers acting independently.  Their detected results can be combined in whatever way is appropriate (perhaps the logical-OR would suffice?), but if the RF is treated coherently, then they interfere with each other to give a linear dependence and thus a dipole response along some other axis in space.

If you are prohibited from doing this (as the text seems to imply, but does not explain why), then you have painted yourself into a corner and a solution is impossible.  At best, you can push the nulls to directions the system is unlikely to see -- but you "cannot comb a sphere", and nulls must necessarily be present somewhere, if combining them coherently.

Comment: That was my worry that I will have to use antenna diversity. Frankly, that's how my current revision is designed (with bilateral switches both for switching antennas and capacitors).

Design constraint is very unfortunate, but I'm space constrained and I still have to implement switched capacitor for tuning (which takes a lot of PCB space).

Answer (score 1):

> *I would like to hear your ideas. Which circuit would be most suitable?*

I would go with the series coil circuit.

With parallel coils, the two coils that are **not** receiving magnetic energy act as a potential divider to the one that is receiving magnetic energy. Given that it's more likely you are wanting to achieve a voltage output, the series coil arrangement would be superior.

Comment: In other answer @Tim Williams suggested antenna diversity. Because I'm space constrained regarding pcb, a simple solution like series connection would be live saver. Do you think that in real life scenario, where interrogating field is present, the other coils wouldn't interfere by receiving the same signal (assuming correct "in-phase" winding connection)?
I treat this circuit as air transformer with three coils, but I have trouble to find a good resources how to approach the problem. If you would have suggestion what kind of book or application note would lead me to correct conclusions?

Comment: The 2 other coils won't produce a signal if 1 coil is 100% aligned. Is this what you want? I don't do book suggestions because I don't read books. I have not come across an application note either. If all three coils receive a fraction of the field there may be some voltage cancellation. If this is not what you want then maybe you need something more like what Tim suggests. I was basing my answer on what you said in your question: *you can think about it as a field detector*. Maybe try it and see. Shouldn't take more than an hour to setup.